# How to render random numbers with view functions of Python Flask?

Tags: python, flask, random, flask-wtforms

I´m trying generate new random numbers with view functions in Python Flask, but the numbers are always the same in the same web session.

Here the first simplified code version:

```py
def random_expression():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    operator = random.choice(["+", "-", "*", "/"])
    return f"{num1} {operator} {num2}"

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    expression = IntegerField(label=random_expression(),default=None)
    

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    return render_template("index.html",form=form)
```

It´s like the random_expression() was executed only once no matter how many times the view function index() is called.

Now trying to remove the function random_expression() from the inside MyForm e put it into the view function() index() in order to refresh the expression string every new execution of index().

The second simplified code version:

```py
def random_expression():    
    num1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 10)
    operator = random.choice(["+", "-", "*", "/"])
    return f"{num1} {operator} {num2}"

class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    str_expression = '0 + 0'
    input = IntegerField(label=str_expressao,validators=[DataRequired()])   

@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    expression = random_expression()
    form.input.label = expression
    return render_template("index.html",form=form)
```

Now, the first execution rendered the random expression and so far so good. The second execution and so on redered always the string literal inside the MyForm class

Comment: The `random_expression` is evaluated only once when the class is created. This expression `IntegerField(label=random_expression(),default=None)` is evaluated to `IntegerField(label="returned string", default=None)`.

Comment: I understand... And what is the correct way to put new string in form field every time the view function index() is called?

Comment: Random expression needs to be generated inside the `index` function. Adding `form.expression.label = random_expression()` after `form = MyForm()` may work.

Comment: Following your tip... I´ve chaged the code and the form is created with a StringField whose label is a string literal. The random expression (random numbers and random operator) is generated in the view function index(). The first execution rendered the random expression and so far so good. The second execution and so on redered always the string literal inside the MyForm class. BTW, I´m running the app using the flask embedded wsgi server.

Comment: Pleas edit your question to include the updated code. I could not reproduce your problem after setting the label in the view function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the label (text) before each rendering. Initially the *expression* could have a dummy label. Something like this:

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    expression = IntegerField(label='', default=None)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()
    form.expression.label.text = random_expression()
    return render_template("index.html", form=form)
```